# Excluding a Metric from a Visualisation Filter

Tags: filter, metrics, microstrategy

I am a new user to MicroStrategy Developer and am stuck with a task that I want to do.  I have created a table visualisation and applied two filters to the visualisation via the visualisation filters:

1. Top 10 Rank by Volume Filter
2. A current month Filter

My table has the following table headings:

1. Region
2. Sales Person Name
3. Sales Volume
4. Average Sales Volume To Date

I want the table to display the Current Months values for the 1st three columns and then the last column to display the average sales volume to date (based on 2 years worth of data).  However clearly Average Sales Volume is not working correctly, I am assuming this is due to the Month filter applied to the visualisation.

Being a new user to MicroStrategy, I am not sure how best to get round this?  Is there a way of making the Average Sales Volume To Date metric independent of the Date filter applied to the visualisation?  Or a better way to build this without applying visualisation filters?

Any hints or tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure whether this works out but you can give it a try.
Create the "Average Sales Volume To Date" metric as a level metric and set the filtering as Ignore.